# How to call thumbnail by aqua resizer in best practice. Specify image dimensions's notify from GTmetrix

Tags: images

I am using [Aqua resizer](https://github.com/syamilmj/Aqua-Resizer) to resize thumbnail on my loop. More flexible than using thumbnail from WordPress. The problem is, image result by Aqua Resizer's has no width and height pixel. The are missing width and/or height attributes.
It's decrease the load speed as shown by GTmetrix.

Here my code to call the image on the loop:

```
 <?php $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); 
    $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 150, 200, true, true, true ); 
 ?>
 <img src="<?php if($image) { echo esc_url($image);
 } else {
 echo catch_that_image();} ?>" alt="<?php  echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
```

Would really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: if you ask for a 150x200 image, isn't it exactly the size you going to get?

Comment: Yes, I get 150 x 200 (not150px x 200px), but when when test on [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com) it's missing width and/or height attributes. Affect to page load speed.

Comment: you know the width and the height, so why don't you just add it there yourself?

Comment: Not a simple as that, the re-size process by HTML. That make the load slower.

Comment: Not sure what are you talking about now. You knwo the width is 150 and the height is 200 so add it as attributes? And no, it doesn't make "whatever" slower but I prefer not to open that can of worms.

Comment: GTmetrix is web to test web performance. Very popular and use by developer to check. No worm on that link. Here what I mean about ["Specify image dimensions"](https://gtmetrix.com/specify-image-dimensions.html) by GTmetrix.

Comment: yeh I know, at this age people just can't be bothered to spend time to learn something by themselves and need some authority figure to tell them what to do. How that authority was granted to that figure, does it really deserve it? those are questions no one bothers to ask. We have GTmatrix and PageSpeed and if either of them will say that you need to sacrifice a virgin to get better score I am sure some people will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's wrong with adding in the attributes as Mark is saying?

```
<?php $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
   $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); 
   $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 150, 200, true, true, true ); 
?>
<img src="<?php if($image) { echo esc_url($image);
} else {
echo catch_that_image();} ?>" width="150" height="200" alt="<?php  echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
```

Comment: look like fixed some issue on test by GTmetrix. Will check for other issue. Thank you.